# Paperclip - images duplication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I would like to not duplicate the image if it's the same that is posted,

Like:

> user1 post an image
>   user2 post the same image
>
> 2 # images in the db

Is there a way to handle that ??

Thanks,

Comment: Just to make sure, but are you sure you want to do this? How does a file get deleted? Does it make sense for two users to link to the same file?

Comment: I took users as examples but in my case yes it makes sense, but you right it was a bad example was just a bit lazy to explain everything ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you'd need to break out your attachments into their own model.

So where you likely now have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :avatar #plus a bunch of specifications here
end
```

You would setup a new model and associations like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :images
end 

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
   has_attached_file :avatar
end
```

Then in your controller, you would need to do

```
Image.find_or_create_by_avatar_file_name(#filename here)
```

So now you have an user.image_id attribute and can have a single uploaded image associated with multiple users.

However, I've built a number of fairly large systems with user photo uploads (badge photos, avatar photos, fun pics, whatever) and the actual overlap between users tends to be quite small. Further, you're really only saving money on what is the cheapest of your resources: storage space. You don't save anything on bandwidth costs, processing or programmatic complexity by going this route.

Unless this is a really unique set of circumstances (in which case it would be neat to hear what you're doing) I would advise against going this route.

Comment: yes I can have a single uploaded image associated with multiple users but ... how can I compare a new uploaded image with the other one ?

Comment: I added some controller code to my answer. You'd need to sort out the uploaded filename and maybe do a comparison on size.

Comment: Thanks, for your complete reply, you definitely right --> storage is cheap even with thousands of duplicate, its ok ...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2913691/Comparing-one-image-to-many-others-speeded-up.aspx

I use it in my program and all fine!

DB related advice: store hashes in table. and then you just need one hash calculation.

About speed

1) Constrain image size 100x100 for example

2) When user try to log in, hash of his password calculated. i think users will login more frequently then update their avatars.

Comment: that makes sense, I'll try that this evening, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the hash of each image as it is saved. When a new user posts the same image, check the hash of that image and see if it matches anything in the database

Comment: yes thats what I thought but I just fear doing a hash on an image each time before saving one would be kind of slow (but didn't try)